# datasource pool size exceeded by Struts ap

Tags: struts2, weblogic

**SQLException weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceLimitException: No resources currently available in pool myDb.datasource to allocate to applications, please increase the size of the pool and retry.. .**

Hi, people.
The above is the error I am getting.  I am working with Struts 2, and I think, that I properly close connections opened throughout various actions, using finally blocks.
I am porting existing application to Struts 2, application originally is written with simply JSP and core Java, no framework whatsoever was used.  I also took care or I think I took care of overriding the main class's finalize method, doing closing connection there.
This is the class that does all the business logic and then mixes the presentation logic to show on JSP Page.
So, the sort of logic used is such:
JSP page, makes calls to Main class's methods. and sometimes to static methods of the Helper class.
Main class in turn, can also use the static methods of the Helper class.

**Can anybody suggest, what else can I look at to remedy the exception above?**  My pool on weblogic is allowing 15 connections now, and considering that there are potentially 1-3 users to my application and even those won't be using it at the same time, I think the pool size is fine and increasing it is not an option for us.

Comment: In terms of general troubleshooting I would suggest that you increase the size of the pool temporarily and see if the problem presents itself again.  If you increase it to 25, for example, and still have the same problem perhaps that would indicate leaked connections.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to look at:

- Enable "Inactive Connection Timeout" on the "Connection Pool" tab of
  the Data Source
- Enable "Profile Connection Leak" on the "Diagnostics"    tab of the
  Data Source

These can help you troubleshoot.  Also, make sure you have a 'finally' block for the try/catch where you reserve your connections that makes sure they are released.

Comment: I do have 'finally' blocks arround my code.  I have suspicion, that the original application is used by someone else for development reasons, and they use the same datasource as myself.  So, even though, I tried to clean up, everywhere I see possibility for the leak... but there could be someone else leaving the door open.